# Right way to do https mutual authentication based on certificates

Tags: .net, authentication, https, client, certificate

I am working on a .net project that needs two-way https authentication based on certificates, i.e., client needs to associate requests with its own certificate and the https server can authenticate the client based on the certificate. I figured out the rough workflow but not sure if it is the right way to do it:

On the client side:

> HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("a request uri");
>     // cert is a X509Certificate2 instance from certStore or a cert file
>     request.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);
> ;

On the server side:

> // req is the HttpListenerRequest instance
>     if (req.ClientCertificateError == 0)
>     {
>         X509Certificate2 clientCert = req.GetClientCertificate;
>         // Validate client certificate
>     }

My questions are:

1) Is this the right way to do it?

2) On the server side, once it get the client certificate associated with the request, what does it do to validate the certificate? Assume we can install the same client certificate on the server.

I am new to the security stuff. Really appreciate it if anyone could help with the questions or point me to useful documents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer depends on how you issue client certificates. Yesterday I described the [procedure of validation in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5603052/https-and-certificates/5603324#5603324). The procedure is quite complicated, but depending on how the client certificates are issued, you can simplify it.

I don't think you will want your visitors buy certificates to just login to your server. This means that you need to issue certificates for the clients yourself. And if you issue these certificates, you can simply put them to the database and when the client connects, check if your clientCert is in the database.

Note that besides certificates themselves you would like to to keep revocation info in the DB in order to let the users know, what happened with their certificate if it's no longer valid.

The procedure of certificate generation is quite a complex topic. I suggest that you read some books on PKI before you proceed. Here are the great books I'd recommend:

1. [Rsa Security's Official Guide to Cryptography](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0072254947)
2. [PKI: Implementing & Managing E-Security](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0072131233)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes I will issue certificates to clients. Could you explain a little bit more about the validation part? Say if the client certificate is installed on the server's cert store already, how do I compare the certificate in the requst with the cert in the local store? by comparing thumbprint...no?

Comment: @gigimei I don't know if it's required to install the client cert in local store, but I guess there must be some other way. The reason is that reading (or doing search within) a couple of thousands of certificates off the store takes quite significant time. As for validation itself - you definitely need to validate integrity by checking certificate's signature. Then you can compare "thumbprints".